# How can I convert a number into a comma separated decimal number?

Tags: jquery

I want to convert the number 64.6 into 64,60.

```
var number = 64.6

var a = parseInt(number);
var b = a.toFixed(2);
var c = b.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
$(".result").html(c);
```

But with my code, the result is 64,00.

Comment: `parseInt` is the issue, use `parseFloat`.

Comment: @BenG Yes, that's it! Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use `/\./g` instead of just `'.'` ?

Comment: because it's a regular expression and `'.'` means "every character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseFloat` as noted by [BenG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000934/beng).

```js
var number = 64.6

var a = parseFloat(number);
var b = a.toFixed(2);
var c = b.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');

console.log(c);
```

Or in a one-liner as pointed out by [Charles-Edward Coste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844857/charles-edouard-coste):

```js
var number = 64.6

var c = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',');

// Note that toFixed converts to a string so there is no need to do another toString

console.log(c);
```

Comment: which can be contracted to: `parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',');`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[WORKING FIDDLE:](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/k45upb0w/8/)

```
    function formatNumber(){
         var number = 64.6;
         number = number.toFixed(2);
         var arr = (number.toString()).split('.',2);
         alert(arr.toString());
    }  

    $(function(){
      formatNumber();
    });
```

Comment: Don't show that code to newbies, dude! This code should be in a named function, not in the `document.ready` callback

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste Sure, Suggestion accepted. Updated the answer.

Comment: Good, but `formatNumber` should be now declared before the `$(function(){..})`